# How to create a kendoui grid programmatically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, grid, kendo-ui

Assuming I have the following grid in my cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Accessibility.Models.CompanyModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Create(update => update.Action("Company", "Company"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetCompanies", "Company"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Company", "Company"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("DestroyCompany", "Company"))
    )
)
```

How do I create the above grid programmatically instead of hard coding it in my cshtml file?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I need to create x number of grids based on user's input

Comment: In that case, does the grid's model structure (i.e. number of columns, events, etc) change for each of the grids, or are the grids merely duplicates with different data with the same model bound?  What I am getting at, is it not possible to create a partial view with the grid markup, and then render the partial view from the controller based on your required logic?

Comment: The columns do not change, but the data does. i.e., under my read action, GetCompanies would probably need to take in a paramter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I would suggest creating a partial view containing the grid's markup, and then in the controller hydrate the model based on the user's input, and then return the partial view and the model.  For example,

```
public ActionResult GetCompanies(int companyId)
{
    CompanyModel model = GetCompanies(companyId);

    return PartialView("_CompaniesGrid", model);
}
```